# How to convert a selected text into a hyperlink in a RichEditBox

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I tried the code below, but it throws exception `System.ArgumentException`,
the exception message is:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

```cs
public void InsertLink(RichEditBox control) 
{  
    control.Document.Selection.Link ="http://www.bing.com";
}
```

Comment: What throws the exception? What line? What's the error **text**? Where did you call the function?

Comment: @devRicher: There's only one executable line and the error text is given in the question.

Comment: I called it from the button click passed the reference of RichEditBox

Comment: So how to link the selection text with URL. I wanna to do something like mail apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The text it contains must be enclosed in quotes, optionally preceded by the sentinel character 0xFDDF. For example: "http://www.msn.com" or 0xFDDF"http://www.msn.com".

You could get more details form MSDN [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextrange.link.aspx).

So you need to change your code like the following:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <RichEditBox x:Name="richeditbox" Height="200">
    </RichEditBox>
    <Button Content="Convert to hypelink" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    richeditbox.Document.Selection.Link = "\"http://www.bing.com\"";  
}
```

Comment: need to call Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates to see the changes            richeditbox.result.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();

Answer (score 1):

Xavier's answer is correct; according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextrange.link.aspx) you need to enclose the URL in quotes. This will only register the selection as a barebones link without any special computed style (i.e. your link won't look any different than plain text but it really is a link). Typically links are styled with an underline, and to do so you would mark it up as an RTF [field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283(v=office.10).aspx#rtfspec_30) like this:

```
var sel = control.Document.Selection;
var rtf = @"{\rtf1{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK ""http://www.bing.com""}{\fldrslt{\ul " + sel.Text + "}}}}";
sel.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtf);
```

I'm not too familiar with RTF, so I don't know if the above code is the most correct way, but it works. It seems that the rich text APIs don't really have a nice way of manipulating fields, so I had to resort to raw RTF markup.